# Is Gaussian Process Regression and Bayesian kernel Machine Regression similar?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, gaussian-process

I was reading Bobb et al. ["Bayesian kernel machine regression for estimating the health effects of multi-pollutant mixtures"](https://academic.oup.com/biostatistics/article/16/3/493/269719) (2015) about Bayesian kernel machine regression. I was wondering if it is the same method as Gaussian Process Regression, just under a different name. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Pretty  much. The paper's novelty is about the hierarchical variable selection approach they introduce.

Comment: @usεr11852 Thanks! would you like to suggest any articles about Bayesian Kernel Machine Regression?

Comment: [Semiparametric Regression of Multidimensional Genetic Pathway Data: Least-Squares Kernel Machines and Linear Mixed Models](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2665800/) by Liu would be an obvious one. In general, it is more of a terminology point than anything else.